# Perl - read text file line by line into array

Tags: arrays, perl, file, line

I have little experience about perl, trying to read simple text file line by line and put all objects in to array. Could you please help ?

Text File:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

Needs to have access for each object in array by index to get access for DDD element for example.

THX

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "fileName";
open (my $FH, '<', $file) or die "Can't open '$file' for read: $!";
my @lines;
while (my $line = <$FH>) {
    push (@lines, $line);
}
close $FH or die "Cannot close $file: $!";

print @lines;
```

To access an array in Perl, use `[]` and `$`. The index of the first element of an array is `0`. Therefore,

```
  $lines[3] # contains DDD
```

see more here : http://perl101.org/arrays.html

Comment: Holy cow, I don't think I've seen anyone link to perl101.org before.  I own it and I'm thinking about letting it lapse, but maybe I shouldn't.  Do you often link to it?

Comment: Why go through all this trouble to slurp a file?

Comment: @AndyLester LOL :D i've used it a few times and it shows up pretty high on Google sometimes :D It's pretty cool, why not keep it ? Sinan that's the way I learned a couple of months ago (from somewhere online - don't remember where from) !

Comment: well, as @ikegami points out, `my @lines = <FH>` would do it. There is no good reason to individually push each line ... unless you are doing something to the lines as your read them. Even just `my @files = <>;` would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks Sinan, didn't know that. I probably was doing something with the lines. The way I wrote this code it feels easier for me to understand, without previously knowing what you said.. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

```
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die("Can't open $qfn: $!\n");

my @a = <$fh>;
chomp @a;
```

As for the last paragraph, I don't know if you mean

```
$a[3]
```

or

```
my @matching_indexes = grep { $_ eq 'DDD' } 0..$#a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "requirements" here seem *extremely minimal* and I agree with @ikegami it's hard to tell if you want to match against text in the array or print out an element by index. Perhaps if you read through [`perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html) you can add to your question and ask for more advanced help based on code you might try writing yourself.

Here is a command line that does what your question originally asked. If you run [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) on your system it will show you the various command line switches you can use for perl one-liners.

- `-0400` - slurps input
- `-a` - autosplits  the file into an array called `@F` using a single white space as the split character.
- `-n` - run in an implicit `while (<>) { }` loop that reads input from the file on
- `-E` - execute the script between `' '`

So with `lines.txt` equal to your text file above:

```
   `perl -0400 -a -n -E 'say $F[3];' lines.txt`
```

outputs: `DDD`